# How do you reset text zoom back to normal in firefox 4?

Tags: firefox

In firefox 3.6 I just had to go to View » Zoom » Reset but I can't find this in Firefox 4.

Where is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, just like you can zoom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

Here it is on OS X:

[image]

Comment: @slhck only way to do it now? They got rid of the view way?

Comment: It's there on OS X, I honestly don't know what they did to Windows

Comment: @slhck - I don't have that toolbar. I have the firefox menu bar in the top left.

Comment: I guess I need to change it to the menu bar view to use that option?

Comment: Supposedly yes. Just my two cents, isn't using the keyboard faster than clicking through two menus?

Comment: @slhck - probably but I don't use it very often so I usually forget the hotkeys.

Comment: Fair enough :) It seems they just stripped seldomly used elements from  the UI in their recent cleanup.

Comment: If you don't want to have menu visible, you can leave it hidden and access it by pressing Alt.